# Simple c program crashes in windows

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am new to c.I Have the following code which creates a double linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
typedef struct Dnode
{
    char c;
    struct Dnode *left;
    struct Dnode *right;
}Dnode;
void insert(Dnode *,char);
void unshift(Dnode *,char);
void travel(Dnode *);
int main(){
    Dnode *cur =  (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));
    Dnode *head = NULL;
    head = cur;

    cur -> c = 'a';
    printf("Cur -> c: %c\n",cur->c);
    cur ->left = NULL;
    cur -> right = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));
    cur->right->c = 'b';
    cur->right->left = cur;
    cur = cur->right;
    travel(head);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void reset(Dnode *h){
    while(h->left)
        h=h->left;
}
void travel(Dnode *head){
    printf("Traversing all nodes of list:\n");
    while(head->right){
        printf("Received char from node %c\n",head->c);
        head = head->right;
    }
    //reset(head);
}
void insert(Dnode * d,char c){
    Dnode *t = d;
    while(t ->right)
        t=t->right;
    t->right = (Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));
    if(t->right){
        t->right->c = c;
        t= t->right;
        t->right = t->left = NULL;
    }
}
void unshift(Dnode *d,char cc){
    Dnode *t =(Dnode *)malloc(sizeof(Dnode));
    t =  d->right;
    t->left =NULL;
    d->left = t;
    d = t;
}
```

The problem is that after travel() is called all the nodes are printed out.
It prints "Received char from node a"
and "Received char from node b"

but then Windows is giving me an error that says that the program has crashed.Any ideas?I would like a detailed answer so as to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the program and see where it's failing.

Comment: You never initialized `cur->right->right`.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a "simple" program. :-P

Comment: @kiner_sah haha true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After initialization your list looks like:

```
   head ------>  X  ------> Y ------> uninitialized
               / ^         /
              /  |        /
             /   \       /
     null<---     -------
```

So in the `travel` function you start by printing `X.c` in the first loop and then use the uninitialized pointer in the second loop. That cause a program crash.

So you need to add:

```
cur->right->c = 'b';
cur->right->left = cur;
cur->right->right = NULL   // Add this line
```

to the initialization.

Also notice that you don't `free` the allocated resources. So in `main` (just before `return`) you should do:

```
Dnode *tmp;
while(head){
    tmp = head;
    head = head->right;
    free(tmp);
}
```

BTW - Don't cast the value returned by `malloc`. Just do `Dnode *cur = malloc(sizeof(Dnode));`

BTW - this line:

```
cur = cur->right;
```

can be deleted as `cur` is not used afterwards.

Comment: The op says it is a double linked list not a tree

Comment: @cssGEEK - Thanks - I got confused by the names, i.e. the pointers are named left and right which is normal for a tree while lists typically use prev and next. Answer updated.

Comment: where do I add it?

Comment: If i don;t cast malloc i get an error.Also with your code update Only 'a' is printed out. 'b' is never printed out

Comment: @JohnKananakis You don't say what error you get, but the most common cause is using C++ instead of C.

Comment: @JohnKananakis - You say: `Only 'a' is printed out` True but that is not due to my update - that is because you have wrong logic in the `travel` function. Use `while(head)` instead of `while(head->right)`

Comment: @JohnKananakis - You say: `If i don;t cast malloc i get an error` Then your not using a compliant C-compiler. In C `malloc` needs no cast and you shouldn't use cast.